# Cutting Stock along with Column Generation

Tags: algorithm, performance, math, optimization, data-structures

I have a client requirement where I need to implement the cutting stock problem along with column generation such that there are similar patterns which can be grouped together to form a bundle.An example is given below

Suppose the following inputs are given:
The rod size available is 120

```
Quantity of Cuts Required-Lengths Required
                        5-16
                        5-30
                        24-36
                        4-18
                        4-28
                        6-20
```

The ideal output would be as follows:

**Bundle 1: 5 Rods**
Cutting pattern in each rod: 16,30,36,36

**Bundle 2: 4 Rods**
Cutting pattern in each rod: 18,28,36,36

**Bundle 3: 3 Rods**
Cutting pattern in each rod: 36,36,20,20

Comment: Column generation is a rather complicated method to implement. What have you done so far ?

Comment: @m.raynal I am going through different optimizers like Gurobi , SCIP etc but I am not sure how to go forward. Can you please suggest me a road map as I am very new to this.
Could you also suggest me if a GPU is required in order to implement the functionality?

Comment: If you're new to linear programming and LP optimization methods, I'd suggest to first get used to solve simple problems without using column generation, and then to try and tackle harder problems using column generation for instance.

Comment: About the optimizer -> there is no silver bullet, and any optimizer will do the job when you begin. I'd suggest you use OPL to write your LP programs since it's the most commonly used language for LPs. When your problem is written in OPL, you can solve it with almost all optimizers. About GPU -> they're not required, and unlike NN frameworks, optimization solvers hardly use GPUs afaik. Classic CPUs do a great job for these tasks